# with which/what and wherewith

Tags: phrases

Let we have the statements like

*We are doing observations by telescopes, by radio-telescopes, by heliometers etc.
But stars do exist independently of `by which (what?) they are (being?) observed`* (??)

I need the correct ending phrase (emphasized) in the last sentence and its, if any, shorter version;
i.e., without mentioning the noun-verb *`they are`*. What I typed above is likely erroneous, sorry.
That is, I'm looking for something like a question-form to the `by` in the 1-st sentence. Here is a guiding analog:

*People do something for bla-bla*

So the question-form for ending phrase here is

*He is doing bla-bla independently of `what for`*.

I see the word `wherewith` in a dictionary.
Collins explains the word as, probably, archaic `with or by which`. Does it help here?

Comment: Please quote the entire sentence. Quoting fragments and placeholders does not help in understanding what you're asking. You found *wherewith* in a dictionary: what did that tell you? Did you find examples of its use (perhaps in a different dictionary)? Please show the results of your research.

Comment: Thanks so much. I retyped the question

Comment: "But stars do exist independently of how they are [being] observed" or "But stars do exist independently of the means by which they are [being] observed"

Answer (score 0):

Telescope need not be used in the plural for these purposes.

The observed exists independently of the means of observation.
The observed exists independent of the tools we use.